# Open the TCP side of a socat connection before the UNIX socket side is connected

Tags: unix, socat

I am using socat to forward from unix domain socket (/var/run/usbmuxd) to TCP port.

```
socat UNIX-LISTEN:/var/run/usbmuxd,mode=777,reuseaddr,fork TCP:10.16.89.10
```

After run socat command, socat does not immediately establish a connection to the TCP port. Just when there data send from unix domain socket then the TCP connection established. Is there anyway to make a TCP connection after run socat command or just send a ping request ?